# Can't install Ubuntu 13.10; freezing on configuring bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: 13.04, system-installation, kernel

For three hours, I have been trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my Gateway MX6445 laptop, but every time, installation stops in the last step.

Comment: Did you read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx/60395#60395

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the Broadcom model for that laptop (Gateway MX6445) is the Broadcom BCM4318 (rev 2) which has a PCI:ID of **14e4:4318**. If this is correct the correct package you should be installing would be the `linux-firmware-nonfree` as shown in the [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx/60395#60395) guide.

Can you confirm this package working, specially because of the (rev 2) part.