# Installation taking a very long time, hangs at "Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source"

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, broadcom, 32-bit

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04(32-bit) on my laptop (Compaq Presario V2000), and after about 7 hours, it is still in `Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source (i386)` mode. The messages I read are as follows:

```
ubuntu kernel: [22814.858163] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPC0.LPC0.ACAD: ACPI_NOTIFY_BUS_CHECK event: unsupported
```

with the numbers in the square brackets increasing.

I have had Windows XP professional on this laptop, and I am erasing it. I am not sure if I should turn off the laptop, and start all over again. About 4 years ago I installed Ubuntu on this laptop, and that was very fast. The only problem I encountered was my wireless, and could not make it to work, and switched back to Windows.

I appreciate any comments regarding this installation taking such a long time.

---

After 40 hours the installation was still in configuring mode with the following messages:

```
ubuntu CRON[29329]: (root) CMD ( cd/ && run-part .. report /etc/cron-hourly)
```

I did the following to check for errors: I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>.

This time the system froze. I had no other choice but to turn off the laptop, and start all over again.
The exact model of the laptop is "Compaq Presario V2069CL Notebook PC" with AMD processor.

---

**Edit**: Started the installation all over again, and did not select the "third party" part. The installation was completed shortly after. However, the wireless does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! IMO your question doesn't have requisite information for us to answer. Please give us more info about your laptop's hardware.

Comment: It looks like it's compiling a driver for a broadcom wifi adapter from source.  Not sure if that means it has to compile an entire kernel and link it in...

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2140893

Comment: Probably hanging installing `wl` driver. If you press ctrl-alt-f2 and do `dmesg` do you see any errors? Linked forum thread suggests `killall -9 modprobe` ought to workaround it. But if you can find the exact error please report it as a bug on Launchpad.

Comment: Looks like same bug: [Launchpad bug #1173206 - 
Installation of 13.04 hangs at "configuring bcmwl-kernel-source"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1173206) and same question as [Can't install Ubuntu 13.10; freezing on configuring bcmwl-kernel-source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446096/cant-install-ubuntu-13-10-freezing-on-configuring-bcmwl-kernel-source)

Comment: Look at the output of `lspci -nn | grep Network`. That will show you your network card. Search for the model number on Ask Ubuntu and you should find instructions on how to install a driver.

Answer (score 1):

Started the installation all over again, and did not select the "third party" part. The installation was completed shortly after. However, the wireless does not work.

Comment: Open "Additional Driver" and try to install the wireless driver. Or follow this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx